# how to apply two's complement to string hex in c#

Tags: c#

I need help conversion my hex string to hex with two's complement in c#

**Exemple: 0x00FEB5AB → 0x00014A55**

My hex. 00FF17DB → ? (this represents negative latitude value)

And 00FCFF75 → ? (this represents negative longitude value)

Thank you =)

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do if you're using 32-bit 2's complement is the following:

```
string hx = "00FF17DB";
uint intVal = Convert.ToUInt32(hx, 16);
uint twosComp = ~intVal + 1;
string h = string.Format("{0:X}", twosComp);
Console.WriteLine(h);
```

So your values should be

00FF17DB → FF00E825

and

00FCFF75 → FF03008B

Hope this helps you

Comment: The exemple: 0x0F7EF73D → 0x008108C3 = 8456387 (decimal)
You exemple return 0F7EF73D →  F08108C3 = 4034988227 why?

thank you so much.

Comment: I need convert latitude (00FF17DB) => 2C (E825) => Dec (59429) / 3600 = -16.508055 AND longitude (00FCFF75) => 2C (3008B) => Dec (196747) / 3600 = -54.651944