# Convert to Hex 2s complement

Tags: c#, integer, data-conversion

I got an integer like this:

```
int myInteger = 1234;
```

What I'd like to get is the **matching Hex signed 2s complement** what should be something similar to this:

```
string hexValueAsString = "052C";
```

---

I tried to use the `.ToString("X2")` method with doesn't work as I thought it would.

```
uint myInteger = 1234;
string hexValueAsString = myInteger.ToString("X2"); // 52C instead of 052C
```

---

What in the world am I doing wrong?
Any help would be really appreciated.

[> Code Playground](https://rextester.com/DGB70662)

Comment: Leading Zeros are omitted. You may get what you want by formatting the result differently (try `X4` if you expect 4 places max). Or use [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve a decent dynamic padding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to apply two's complement to string hex in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899547/how-to-apply-twos-complement-to-string-hex-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @OlivierRogier That post doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem in hand. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed OP mentioned "2s complement" which you do not get by simply turning an int to a hex string. I just am not sure if OP actually _wants_ [2s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement): _"To get the two's complement of a binary number, the bits are inverted, or "flipped", by using the bitwise NOT operation; the value of 1 is then added to the resulting value, ignoring the overflow which occurs when taking the two's complement of 0. "_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of digits you need beforehand, you may explicitly specify it:

```
string hexValueAsString = myInteger.ToString("X4");
```

If not, you could do something like this:

```
int myInteger = 1234;
string hexValueAsString = myInteger.ToString("X");
if (hexValueAsString.Length % 2 == 1)
    hexValueAsString = hexValueAsString.Insert(0, "0");
```